# Is there an alternative App to Mail on iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, email

I'm looking for another app than Mail on my iPad. I have searched the appStore without success.

Is there not other emailers on iPad ?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in this Mail alternative?

Comment: It's in fact I don't want to merge my emails and the one of my wife in the same App. I will use the other one, leaving Mail for her. It's an idea to get along with the fact that there is no "session" on the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to use **Gmail web app** and add it to the dashboard.

The iPad web interface is pretty nice, I believe it works offline, too. One of the main problem is that there's no new mail notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gmail then have a look at:

1. [Inbox2](http://www.inbox2.com)
2. [Mailing Desk](http://www.thoughtoutapps.com/mailing-desk/)

Inbox2 even lets you integrate your conversations from other webapps (twitter, facebook, linkdin), if that is something relevant for you.

Comment: The Inbox2 URL says it is for Windows, and the Mailing Desk link is giving a 404 error.